# How can we extract the specific value from pdf using python?

Tags: python, pip, nlp

Is there a way to get specific text from pdf using NLP or python library

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [pdfreader](https://pypi.org/project/pdfreader/) to extract texts (plain and containing PDF operators) from PDF document

Here is a sample code extracting all the above from all document pages.

```
from pdfreader import SimplePDFViewer, PageDoesNotExist

fd = open(you_pdf_file_name, "rb")
viewer = SimplePDFViewer(fd)

plain_text = ""
pdf_markdown = ""
try:
    while True:
        viewer.render()
        pdf_markdown += viewer.canvas.text_content
        plain_text += "".join(viewer.canvas.strings)
        viewer.next()
except PageDoesNotExist:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

First you install PyPDF2 library using below command:

`pip install PyPDF2`

**type this code:**

```
Import PyPDF2
mypdf=open(”/home/Desktop/sample.pdf”, mode=”rb”)
pdf_document=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(mypdf) `
```

Now creating pdfobject as pdf_document, how much page in pdf then used `pdf_document.numPages`

`first_page=pdf_document.getPage(0)
print( first_page.extractText() )`

Now you can read pdf file.

if you have any misunderstanding in my answer, please refer to the below link:

[Python for NLP: Working with Text and PDF Files](https://stackabuse.com/python-for-nlp-working-with-text-and-pdf-files/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either use tika, textract or PyPDF2

```
from tika import parser
data = parser.from_file('your_pdf.pdf')
print(data['text'])
```